# Highstocks: Panning not working in yAxis

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way in highstock for panning to work in `yAxis`. I have set `max` in `yAxis` so that the user cannot see data above the `max yAxis` value by default. However I want to give user the ability to pan and see the data beyond the `max` `yAxis` value.

Example in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/fMkW5/) where `max` `yAxis` is set to 200.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        panning: true
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        max: 200
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately panning works only for xAxis.

Comment: Can you please see my yAxis panning code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186620/highcharts-panning-in-yaxis-is-happening-too-slowly and check whether it can be made quicker.